# Converting date format in PHP to Y-m-d H:i:s fails

Tags: php, date

I have date in format like 23:44 01.03.2016, I need to format it to: `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Here is what I try:

```
$article_date = strtotime($date);
$article_date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$article_date);
```

where $date is 23:44 01.03.2016.

The code returns `1970-01-01 01:00:00`. I've also tried different dates, similar outcome. How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you mention what echo $date; gives?

Comment: It seems to me your first assignment ($article_date = strtotime($date);) is failing and then $article_date is null. Then the second one reads it like UNIX standard time.

Comment: Check this : https://eval.in/536718

Comment: Maybe you should change the name of $date. It is not good to have a variable whose name is a function name. It may lead to confusion sometimes.

Comment: Echo $date gives 23:44 01.03.2016 and it seems that strtotime() is failing. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('23:44 01.03.2016');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

for more details on the object DateTime [check this](http://www.paulund.co.uk/datetime-php)

Comment: Second parameter is timestamp

Comment: is the problem solved ?

Comment: No, problem is not solved yet

Comment: did u tried the above one.

Comment: This works: https://eval.in/536835

Comment: Now its fine, problem is solved. Thank You very much!

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!